# Jquery click and toggleClass question

Tags: jquery, navigation, click, hover, toggleclass

here's my probably (and hopefully) simple problem:

i have a list with images as navigation. when you hover over them, jquery animates a div with a caption and shows it. it disapears on mouseout. (works fine)

when you click on the image, the caption div animates further and is overlaying the image completly (works fine). while hovering over another image in the nav the caption div animates aswell (works fine).

the problem: when clicking a second navigation image, the animation of the first one(clicked) should disapear.

here's the jquery:

```
var thumbslide = $('.boxgrid.captionfull').click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('clicked').children('.cover').stop().animate({top: 0, height:"230px", opacity: 1}, 350);
});
$('.boxgrid.captionfull:not(.clicked)').live('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).children('.cover').stop().animate({top: 130}, 350);
}).live('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).children('.cover').stop().animate({top: 230}, 350);
})
```

and here's a link to the [dev site](http://tobiasmay.net/kunden/aks/projekte)

any help is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This removes the `clicked` class and animates it back down and returns the opacity back to 0.7:

```
var thumbslide = $('.boxgrid.captionfull').click(function() {
   $('.boxgrid.captionfull.clicked').removeClass('clicked').children('.cover').stop().animate({top: 230, opacity: 0.7}, 350);
   $(this).toggleClass('clicked').children('.cover').stop().animate({top: 0, height:"230px", opacity: 1}, 350);
});
```

Comment: awesome. works. but why did jamiecs code (w/o the animation part) only work when hovering again over the last item? i mean.. it did remove the class but shouldn't it then also return to its previous state? just wondering..

Comment: Because your `mouseenter` / `mouseleave` code sets the `top` value.  So when you moused over it it would still do that animation but the opacity would not be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

Isnt this just a case of finding any other clicked item and removing its clicked class?

```
var thumbslide = $('.boxgrid.captionfull').click(function() {
   $('.boxgrid.captionfull.clicked').removeClass('clicked');
   $(this).toggleClass('clicked').children('.cover').stop().animate({top: 0, height:"230px", opacity: 1}, 350);
});
```

Comment: guess its kinda the way to go, but when i try it that way, it only removes the clicked class while hovering over the previously clicked element..

Comment: @tobiasmay - can you set up a simplified jsfiddle showing the issue. www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: guess the fiddle is obsolete now.. but thank you very much for the effort!